# Spring Boot thin jar in multi module project giving error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am having a multi module project in Spring Boot and trying to use thin jars , but it doesnt seem to work . Folder structure

```
app ( com.xxx.app)
|
 adapter/rest ( module not containing start class)
 adapter/sns ( module not containing start class)
 application ( module containing start class) (com.xxx.application)
 pom.xml ( pom.xml of parent app)
```

pom.xml of app folder

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>${thin-jar.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.xxx.application.MobileNotificationSvcApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${thin-jar.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Download the dependencies at build time into target/thin/root/ -->
                        <id>resolve</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resolve</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

pom.xml of module containing main class

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    <mainClass>com.xxx.application.MobileNotificationSvcApplication</mainClass>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

other modules dont contain any spring boot maven plugin.

When I run mvn clean install -f  , jars are created in target folder of each module ( very small size) but no target/thin/root directory is created in any module. Also when I start the jar of the module containing main class , I get below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:139)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot build model
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.DependencyResolver.dependencies(DependencyResolver.java:253)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.PathResolver.extract(PathResolver.java:259)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.PathResolver.resolve(PathResolver.java:105)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ThinJarLauncher.java:369)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ThinJarLauncher.java:352)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.getClassPathArchivesIterator(ThinJarLauncher.java:200)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:55)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.launch(ThinJarLauncher.java:195)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.main(ThinJarLauncher.java:141)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: hidden.org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.xxx:application:${revision}
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xxx:application:${revision}: Could not find artifact com.xxx:app:pom:${revision} in spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot) @ line 6, column 13
 for project com.xxx:application:${revision}
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:165)
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:123)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.DependencyResolver.dependencies(DependencyResolver.java:213)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: hidden.org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.xxx:mobile-notification-configuration:${revision}
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xxx:application:${revision}: Could not find artifact com.xxx:app:${revision} in spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot) @ line 6, column 13

        at hidden.org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProblemCollector.newModelBuildingException(DefaultModelProblemCollector.java:197)
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1082)
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:830)
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:332)
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:158)
        ... 16 more
```

Comment: If you are using `${revision}` you have to use flatten maven plugin...(check: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) ... why changed the life cycle binding for the spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a setup similar to:

```
app (com.xxx.app) - Parent Project
│
├── adapter/rest (module)
├── adapter/sns (module)
└── application (module with Main class)
    └── pom.xml (module POM)
pom.xml (parent POM)
```

Maven cannot resolve the parent POM for your `application` module, specifically pointing to an issue with `${revision}` not being resolved. That might indicate a problem with property resolution in your multi-module setup, particularly if `${revision}` is meant to be a dynamic versioning property.

Your configuration of the thin JAR plugins seems correct, but the error precedes its execution phase. So the issue is with the Maven's project structure resolution rather than the thin JAR mechanism itself.

Make sure that the `${revision}`, `${spring-boot-maven-plugin.version}`, and `${thin-jar.version}` properties are correctly defined in your parent `pom.xml` or in a properties file that Maven can access. Properties should be defined in the parent POM to make sure they are inherited by child modules:

```xml
<properties>
    <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    <spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>2.5.0</spring-boot-maven-plugin.version>
    <thin-jar.version>1.0.25.RELEASE</thin-jar.version>
</properties>
```

But if, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949799/spring-boot-thin-jar-in-multi-module-project-giving-error#comment137428363_77949799) by [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise), `${revision}` is supposed to work with "[Maven CI Friendly Versions](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)", then do incorporate the Flatten Maven Plugin:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version> <!-- current Q1 2024 latest version -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- Configuration options here -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>flatten</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten.clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Execute Maven with the `-X` flag (e.g., `mvn clean install -X`) to get more detailed output. That can help identify where the resolution process fails.